# Azure kubernetes installation

Tags: azure, kubernetes, region

I cant install AKS in azure, because it doesnt allow me to choose a region. I have selected every possible region, but is not possible to use it. I am using a student account in europe. Can you please let me know which region to use?

KR

[image]

Comment: Your account may not allow the creation of AKS clusters. Contact your sponsor or Azure support.

Comment: Can you please provide the information of the policy that is shown in the location denied error.

Answer (score 0):

> **Policy enforcement value does not meet requirements on resource Microsoft.ContainerService/manageCluster The field location with with
> the value US(westus3) is denied**

***[PolicyEnforcement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/decision-guides/policy-enforcement/#:%7E:text=Azure%20Policy%20is%20an%20Azure,standards%20and%20service%2Dlevel%20agreements.)*** in azure you can apply configuration setting and resource creation rules at the subscription level , Resource Group and Resource level as well.

***[Azure Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/overview)*** is an Azure service for creating, assigning, and managing policies. These policies enforce different rules and effects over your resources, so those resources stay compliant with your corporate standards and service-level agreements.

So based on above statement could say there might be policy enforcement from your ***Administrator*** or might be set a default policy from Azure Side for student account to do not create the AKS.

As for ***Azure Student account*** This benefit provides you access to a free tier of the following services:

•   Azure App Service

•   Azure Functions

•   Azure Notification Hubs

•   Azure Database for MySQL

•   Application Insights

•   Azure DevOps Services (formerly Visual Studio Team Services)

For more information you can refer this ***[Document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0144p/)***